# problem with # character in name in postgres and h2 db

Tags: sql, postgresql, hash, character, h2

I have a set of book names which I am adding to a `Books` table.
The names are all copied from amazon website

```
1.The Winter King (The Arthur Books #1)
2.Enemy of God (The Arthur Books #2)
```

when I add these to the table ,and later try a query using the exact name,I get no results.I tried postgres and h2 databases.

Finally,when I listed the items using

```
>>select b.name from Books b;

The Winter King (The Arthur Books
Enemy of God (The Arthur Books
```

It seems that the # character is omitted..So,how do I get around this?Do I have to modify all my data by removing the # character from the entries? or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

When using CSV import (`CSVREAD`) in an older version of H2, then the `#` character is parsed as a line comment. This is no longer the case by default for H2 version 1.3.150 and newer, as described in the [change log](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html).

Comment: playframework uses h2 for testing.I came across this problem there..Is this an issue with postgres too?

Comment: I put it in a yaml file and let the application load it at startup

Comment: Could you append ;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3 to the H2 database URL, and then verify what is inserted in to the database by looking at the .trace.db file? (works in H2 only)